# Detect if the user has closed the window, not reloaded it. React

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, window

I understand how to use beforeunload, but I need to determine if it was just a page reload or if the page has been closed for a while. I suppose this can be somehow beat localStorage / sessionStorage. Save in storage the time?

Thanks!

Comment: https://dev.to/eons/detect-page-refresh-tab-close-and-route-change-with-react-router-v5-3pd Please have a look at this. It should answer your question

Comment: Thanks, good solution. However, I would not like to "throw out an alert", as I understand it, it is impossible to track a click on the "cross"

Comment: You can add your custom code instead of the alert, did you go though the article?

Comment: I re-read more carefully, I just have Nextjs, I'm trying to figure it out